# How to make boost::thread sleep for N ticks?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have ammount of ticks that a thread shall sleep. How to make it sleep for N ticks?

Comment: (ticks is received in long long form from external counter that does something like `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()` )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say that the value in "ticks" is extracted from the duration type of `high_resolution_clock`; so you'll need to restore that type:

```
this_thread::sleep_for(high_resolution_clock::duration(ticks));
```

Better still, work with the duration types themselves, rather than extracting unitless tick counts from them.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be ticks and you'd be happy with milliseconds then boost::this_thread::sleep should do the job. On windows at least a tick is a millisecond.

Comment: I know, yet I have ticks and see no FromTicks nor in boost::chrono not in posix_time

Comment: @DuckQueen define ticks. If you can measure amount of ticks per millisecond then you can still wait n milliseconds. Unless your precision requirements are higher than this but then you are out of luck with windows as its sleep has a specific resolution, afaik 16ms, lower values may just result in higher interrupt call numbers without gaining better precision and just thrashing the cpu. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/facc2b57-9a27-4049-bb32-ef093fbf4c29/threadsleep1-sleeps-for-156-ms?forum=clr